# Google Custom Search create a huge blank space at the bottom

Tags: javascript, google-custom-search

While working with Google Custom Search (Iframe supported) , it creates a huge blank space at the bottom? How can I avoid that blank space.

For example: this site [ http://www.town.togitsu.nagasaki.jp/search/pub/Default.aspx?c_id=2&q=togitsu&cx=000096980916426724425:keok8sbpuem&cof=FORID:10&ie=UTF-8 ] creates a huge blank space at the bottom.

I have checked the source (http://www.google.com/afsonline/show_afs_search.js) but could not get it out.

Answer (score 0):

Change the height attribute of this iframe to 1260:

```
<iframe name="googleSearchFrame" src="http://www.google.com/cse?c_id=2&amp;q=togitsu&amp;cx=000096980916426724425:keok8sbpuem&amp;cof=FORID:10&amp;ie=UTF-8&amp;ad=n9&amp;num=10&amp;rurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.town.togitsu.nagasaki.jp%2Fsearch%2Fpub%2FDefault.aspx%3Fc_id%3D2%26q%3Dtogitsu%26cx%3D000096980916426724425%3Akeok8sbpuem%26cof%3DFORID%3A10%26ie%3DUTF-8&amp;siteurl=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F10647487%2Fgoogle-custom-search-create-a-huge-blank-space-at-the-bottom" frameborder="0" width="795" height="1260" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" hspace="0" vspace="0" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

This is most likely added in dynamically by the JavaScript code for the search. If that is the case, you'll need to use JavaScript to change the height dynamically:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[name="googleSearchFrame"]').attr("height","1260");
});
```

Comment: By setting height to 1260, you are going to make the iframe fixed height.